# java to send data to MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to make a program that inserts data to mysql but the data that is sent to mysql are null.  I don't know what is wrong with jtextfield but it does not read it and does not send it.

I am working 1 week on that problem. I didn't find anything on the web. Please, I hope to find the answer here.

```
package Electroniclabcy;

import static com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.CorbaResourceUtil.getText;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.jar.Attributes.Name;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import static sun.management.Agent.getText;

/**
 *
 * @author angelos
 */
public class customers extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     private String Name;
    private int Phone;
    private String Email;
    private int Date;

     private String name;
    private int phone;
    private String email;
    private int date;

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;


    public customers( ) {  
        this.Name=name;
        this.Phone=phone;
        this.Email=email;
        this.Date=date;
        initComponents();
    }



    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        javax.swing.JTextField Name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        javax.swing.JTextField Phone = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        javax.swing.JTextField Email = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        javax.swing.JTextField Date = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        javax.swing.JTextField Address = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        javax.swing.JTextField Notes = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        javax.swing.JButton insert = new javax.swing.JButton();
        javax.swing.JButton search = new javax.swing.JButton();
        javax.swing.JButton update = new javax.swing.JButton();
        javax.swing.JButton delete = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("NAME");

        jLabel2.setText("PHONE-NUMBER");

        jLabel3.setText("EMAIL");

        jLabel4.setText("DATE");

        jLabel5.setText("ANDDRESS");

        jLabel6.setText("NOTES");

        Name.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                NameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        insert.setText("jButton1");
        insert.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                insertActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        search.setText("jButton1");

        update.setText("jButton1");

        delete.setText("jButton1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                                .addGap(199, 199, 199))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(Name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(Email))
                                .addGap(21, 21, 21)))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(Phone)
                            .addComponent(Date)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                .addGap(0, 36, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addComponent(Notes)
                    .addComponent(Address))
                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(insert)
                    .addComponent(search)
                    .addComponent(update)
                    .addComponent(delete))
                .addContainerGap(153, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(insert))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Name, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(Phone, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(search))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Email, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(Date, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(Address, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(update)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(delete))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(Notes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void NameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void insertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        try{
String sql = "INSERT INTO customers"
+"(name, phone, email,date)"
+"VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/customers","root","");
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, Name);
pst.setInt(2, Phone);
pst.setString(3, Email);
pst.setInt(4,  Date);
pst.executeUpdate();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "inserted successfully");

}
catch(SQLException | HeadlessException ex){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(customers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(customers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(customers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(customers.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new customers().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }



      private String getText(Object Name) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `getText().toString()` method?

```
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, Name.getText().toString());
pst.setInt(2, Phone.getText().toString());
pst.setString(3, Email.getText().toString());
pst.executeUpdate();
```

this will get the text from the `textbox` and will format it to a `String`, which you can use to do whatever you want to.

Comment: is says can not find symbol

Comment: i cannot paste the error but i can write it it says cannot find symbol symbol:method geText() location:variable Date of type Object

Comment: This is because, when you try to enter date in text-field you either do 00-00-0000 or 00/00/0000, which contains symbols(-, /) and since you are converting that text into int datatype, it gives you error because -, / can't be converted into int.my recommendation for using date would be using datatimepicker object. its a simple gui object which let you pick the date.pls if have find it usefull, don't forget to mark my answer.Hope that helps

Comment: yes but this is do it also to the other objects like name phone email

Comment: yep, because i can now see that you are using two variables of the same name. delete this but and try again.pls you have posted very messy code, try to be more neat. 
     private String Name;
    private int Phone;
    private String Email;
    private int Date;